# How to mask a field like SSN or ID field?

Tags: sharepoint-server, column, security

Is there way to mask a field like social security number or ID field? I like mask field both in list view level, edit form and view form. Is it possible?

Sharepoint 2013 (we have nintex form as well)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a custom column type to achieve this. Using JS to complete this is more troublesome, especially in list view.
[Demo](http://sharethepunto.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-create-custom-field-type.html)

I write a demo in new form for your reference, you need to change css file to achieve better effect:

```
<style>
.num{
                position:relative;
}
.number{
                position: absolute;
}
.value{
                position: absolute;
                top:0;
                color: transparent !important;
                background: transparent;
                border:none;
}

</style>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$("input[title='Title']").closest("span").attr("class","num")
$("input[title='Title']").after("<input type='text' class='value'><br/><input class='number' type='text'/>")
$("input[title='Title']").hide()

})
    $("body").on('keydown keyup ','.value', function() {
                 var res = this.value, //grabs the value

                                 len = res.length, //grabs the length
                                 max = 9, //sets a max chars
                                 stars = len>0?len>1?len>2?len>3?len>4?'XXX-XX-':'XXX-X':'XXX-':'XX':'X':'', //this provides the masking and formatting

                                result = stars+res.substring(5); //this is the result
        console.log(res)
                 $(this).attr('maxlength', max); //setting the max length
                $(".number").val(result); //spits the value into the input
                                $("input[title='Title']").val(res)
    });
</script>
```

Test Result:
[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367230/masking-a-social-security-number-input